# C#: преобразовать строку в массив байтов

Tags: c#, конвертация, hex

Есть строка `"612345"`. HEX-editor преобразует ее в следующий массив: `{36 31 32 33 34 35 36}`. Я хочу добавить эти значения (т.е. 36,31,...36) в массив байтов:

```
byte[] t = {0x36, 0x31, 0x32 ... 0x36}
```

только не хардкорно, а **программно**.

Я добился того, что в строке уже есть HEX-значения: "36 31 32 33 34 35 36" теперь надо как-то добавить перед каждым "0х" и добавить в массив. Подскажите, как это сделать!

Comment: 0x - это конструкция на уровне исходного кода, для того, чтобы компилятор понял что это числа в hex. в рантайме ее не существует, и все числа храняться в бинарном виде, вне зависимости от их представления в тексте программы.

Comment: строку "612345" преобразовать в байты можно так: `Split("612345", 2).Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16))` -- метод Split - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478201/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B/478202#478202)

Comment: По теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так должно сработать:

```
var s = "36 31 32 33 34 35 36";
var bytes = s.Split(' ').Select(_ => int.Parse(_, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить массив байт по строке, нужно воспользоваться методом Encoding.GetBytes
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Судя по значениям, тебе подойдёт ASCIIEncoding (учти, что не все символы в ней представимы) и UTF8Encoding. Учти, что .NET использует UnicodeEncoding (она же UTF16) для хранения строк, и любые преобразования не всегда однозначны, хотя well-formed строку в UTF16 можно привести в UTF8 и наоборот. Про ASCII даже такое утверждение неверно.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Если ты хочешь получить генерацию кода, просто примени к массиву байт Select с приведением в 16ричную систему счисления в нужном виде и String.Join для объединения в строку.

Comment: А за что минус? Правильный же ответ. Байты строки без кодировки вовсе не имеют смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Преобразование строки в массив байт:

```
// ожидает строку без пробелов, "612345"
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
  int NumberChars = hex.Length;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return bytes;
}
```

Обратное преобразование:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

или

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
  return hex.Replace("-","");
}
```

<sub>[оригинальный ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/1988244)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] str = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello world");
```

самый простой способ