# Расшифровка сообщения в 3DES

Tags: c#, шифрование, криптография

Добрый день!

Имеется сообщение, длинной 16 байт, и имеется ключ, тоже длинной 16 байт. Я пытаюсь расшифровать это сообщение этим ключом:

```
string MasterKey = "40ADC7B0A11F4AE96D5238768CF1C708";

byte[] masterkey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MasterKey);
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider trp_d = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

trp_d.Key = masterkey;
trp_d.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
trp_d.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

byte[] result = new byte[256];

var decr = trp_d.CreateDecryptor();

var d = decr.TransformBlock(result, 0, result.Length, result, 0);
```

Код падает на строке: `trp_d.Key = test_key ;` с ошибкой

> Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.

Я пытался устанавливать KeySize  в 16*8 (т.к. в битах), но все равно та же ошибка.

Как можно заставить программу все-таки расшифровать сообщение этим ключом?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8fdfcce7-3a8a-4271-8557-3df715c80df8/weak-key-cryptographic-exception). Это, безусловно, уродское решение, но уж какое есть.

Comment: Если C можно использовать - openSSL не ругается на ключи.

Comment: Я исправил текст ошибки. посмотрите,  пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно задаёте `MasterKey`. Создав строку следующим образом:

```
string MasterKey = "40ADC7B0A11F4AE96D5238768CF1C708";
```

Вы получаете строку состоящую из **32** символов(это не вся проблема, есть ещё та, что каждый символ преобразуется в байт, который отличен от символа). Когда Вы приводите эту строку к массиву байт, Вы получает 32 байта, что есть 256 бит. Алгоритм, который Вы используете [поддерживает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key(v=vs.110).aspx) ключи размером от 128 до 192 бит:

> This algorithm supports key lengths from 128 bits to 192 bits in
>   increments of 64 bits.

Чтобы избавиться от ошибки, нужно правильно задавать MasterKey:

```
var MasterKey = new byte[]{ 0x40, 0xAD, 0xC7..., 0x08};
```

Comment: Или можно [вот так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420023/10105).