# Конвертация байтов

Tags: c#, типы-данных, конвертация

Есть строка **"15"**. Как программно "приписать" перед числом  **"0х"** чтобы можно было произвести такой расчет:

```
Convert.ToByte(0x15) = 21;
```

т.е.:

```
Convert.ToByte("0x" + "15") = 21`;
```

Как правильно сделать эту запись?

Comment: Похоже на повтор http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420019/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Convert.ToByte("15", 16);
```

16 — это основание системы счисления. `"0x"` не нужен.

Получится ожидаемое число 21. Проверка: http://ideone.com/n4xd75