# string - byte[] - sha1 - hex - sha1 - byte[] - string

Tags: c#, hex, sha1

Есть строка, которую преобразовываю в HEX

```
{
    string s = "this string covnert to hex";
    string sHex = HexSHA1UTF8string(s);
}

private static string HexSHA1UTF8string(string s)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

            var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);

            return HexStringFromBytes(hashBytes);
        }

private static string HexStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                var hex = b.ToString("x2");
                sb.Append(hex);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Как теперь из sHex вернуть S ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. SHA1 - необратимое преобразование.

Comment: если убрать пункт преобразования в sha1
такое обратное преобразование возможно string - byte[] - hex - byte[] - string?

Comment: Да, разумеется. В гугле полно примеров по ключевым словам "c# hex decode".

Comment: @TonyDM: да. [разбиваете на куски](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420023/10105), получаете байты, кодируете в string.