# Как разделить строку на равные части определенной длины?

Tags: c#, строки

Как нарезать строку на равные части/фрагменты определенного размера?
Требуется функция, в которую можно передать любую строку и указать размер фрагмента. Если строка не делится на равные части, то последняя часть может быть короче предыдущих.
Например, для строки "68656c6c6f" надо получить ее части `{"68","65",...}`.
Как это сделать на C#?

Comment: Примера тут недостаточно для понимания задачи. Нужно ровно три части? Все части ровно по два символа? Что если длина строки — простое число, как ее делить на равные части?

Comment: @NickVolynkin _"Примера тут недостаточно для понимания задачи."_ -- исправил текст в вопросе. _"Что если длина строки — простое число"_ -- по идее последняя часть будет заполнена не полностью.

Comment: Подобная задача (с разбиением hex-строки на байты) уже попадалась несколько раз раньше.

Comment: @VladD _"задача (с разбиением hex-строки на байты) уже попадалась"_ -- там делится строка именно на байты. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420019/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#comment545940_420019). а этот вопрос о разделении на подстроки определенного размера.

Comment: @Stack, но строка остается _hex-строкой_? или в ней могут присутствовать любые символы?

Comment: @Grundy _"строка остается hex-строкой?"_ -- строка может быть любой. например: qwerrfvwwwzaw -- и ее надо нарезать по 4 символа.

Comment: так в чем все-таки вопрос? получить _массив байт_ или разбить строку на группу символов?

Comment: @Grundy _"так в чем все-таки вопрос?"_ -- сам вопрос в заголовке. разбивать надо на равные части определенного/любого размера. а про байты - это только для примера.

Comment: Ага, вот теперь стало гораздо конкретнее.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с регулярным выражением из [подобного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

```
var s1 = "68656c6c6f";
var chunkSize = 2;
var result = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(s1, @".{1,"+chunkSize+"}") 
              select m.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: если в последнем chunk'е не будет хватать символов, то regex его не вернет. а как сделать, чтобы вернул?

Comment: @Stack, не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду, для строки "12345" - данный код вернет три группы: "12", "34", "5". Вы что-от другое имели ввиду?

Comment: все ок. просто я `"{m,n}"` перепутал с `"{n}"`, т.к. регулярные выражения использую редко.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<string> Split(TextReader sr, int size, bool fixedSize = true) {
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) {
        var buffer = new char[size];
        var c = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, size);
        yield return fixedSize ? new String(buffer) : new String(buffer, 0, c);
    }
}
IEnumerable<string> Split(string s, int size, bool fixedSize = true) {
    var sr = new StringReader(s);
    return Split(sr, size, fixedSize);
}
```

Пример

```
var s1 = "68656c6c6f";
var ba = Split(s1, 2)  // делим s1 на части
         .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)) // конвертируем в байты
         .ToArray();
var s2 = Encoding.Default.GetString(ba);  // "hello"
```

Пример

```
var s1 = "61234";
var en = Split(s1, 2, false).Select(s => s.PadLeft(2, '0'));
var s2 = String.Join("; ", en);    // "61; 23; 04"
```

---

Вариант на основе Rx

```
#r "System.Reactive"

using System.Reactive.Linq;

var str = "12345";
foreach (var g in Observable.Buffer(str.ToObservable(), 3).ToEnumerable())
   Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(g));
```

результат

```
123
45
```

Comment: Делить строку на символы таким образом — не самая хорошая идея. Потому что возможны суррогатные пары и [диакритика](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/).

Comment: Плюс `Encoding.Default` практически никогда не бывает правильным.

Comment: _"возможны суррогатные пары"_ -- строки появляются не сами по себе. а вообще - да, все возможно, и наверное где-то используют римские цифры. но, как правило, код не пишут на всякий случай, а только тот, который реально необходим.

Comment: @VladD, подозреваю, что в вопросе имелись ввиду только _hex-строки_, соответственно и диакритических символов в ней не будет

Comment: @Stack При использовании StringReader-а появляется одно лишние копирование(string -> char array -> string) и один дополнительный уровень косвенности (string -> StringReader). 
У варианта через Rx затраты еще выше.

Comment: @Serj-Tm _"При использовании StringReader-а появляется одно лишние копирование"_ -- тут StringReader для того чтобы в первый Split передать TextReader -- он нужен для работы с большими  файлами в одну строку (т.е. нет \n\r) и которые невозможно загрузить целиком.

Comment: @Stack Да, возможно такое решение. Постановка задачи под такое решение: универсальное решение для разбиения произвольного потока символов (string, file и т.д.) на строки фиксированной длины.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> Split(this string text, int size) 
{
   for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i += size)
      yield return text.Substring(i, Math.Min(size, text.Length - i));
}
```

Comment: У вас в `i += size` потерялось `i`.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо!

Comment: @Serj-Tm а если text находится в файле где нет \r\n, т.е. только одна строка, а файл на 4 gb телеметрии какого-то двигателя. например: 2342 4455 3312 4421 .... и надо прочесть 100 чисел из середины файла.

Comment: @Stack Тогда это будет другая задача "прочитать 100 чисел из середины файла" с другим кодом для ее решения.